# Message sent to deallocated instance in swift

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, google-ima

I'm getting an error that causes the app to crash. My application having list of the videos(My application screen divided in two part, one for player and second for videos list). I am using `AVPlayerViewController` for play the video. If user clicks continuously two item that the app to crash.

> I have tried to run using NSZombie and I get the following message :
>   An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated 'FigPlaybackItem'
>   object (zombie) at address: 0x14734ed00.

[image]

Do you have any idea of how to solve this issue?

Here is the output from Allocation instrument with NSZombies Detection if it helps:

[image]

Comment: Double click the arrow and again click the line it shows you the exact error line.

Comment: I have went with your instruction and get the error. But i am not understand. [Please check this link](https://s16.postimg.org/jsndvqm3p/Screen_Shot_2016_10_13_at_6_13_28_PM.png)